# Showing message in ng-repeat when search string array is empty in angular

Tags: angularjs

```
<ul class="data-ctrl mCustomScrollbar" id="scrollbar" data-mcs-theme="minimal-dark dark123" data-ng-init="initScrollBar()">
                    <li data-ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString | limitTo:limit" >
                        <p><a data-ng-href="{{i.link}}" class="search-link">{{i.title}}</a></p>
                        <p>{{i.description}}</p>
                        <p><a class="small" data-ng-href="{{i.link}}">{{i.link}}</a></p>        
                <li data-ng-repeat-empty >No Records Found</li>     
                    </li>

                </ul>
```

I am providing search option to the user using above code.when i am trying to show message like no record found when search string is empty from my json db file using data-ng-repeat-empty, but problem is 'No Records Found' showing for both cases like Record found and record not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the filter data in variable and then check the length of variable it will work.

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="i in filterItem = (items | searchFor:searchString | limitTo:limit)" >
       <p><a data-ng-href="{{i.link}}" class="search-link">{{i.title}}</a></p>
       <p>{{i.description}}</p>
       <p><a class="small" data-ng-href="{{i.link}}">{{i.link}}</a></p>        
    </li>
    <li ng-if="!filterItem.length">No Records Found</li> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check `items.length` with **`ng-if`** or **`ng-show`**

And put your message out side the `ng-repeat`

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="i in items | searchFor:searchString | limitTo:limit" >
       <p><a data-ng-href="{{i.link}}" class="search-link">{{i.title}}</a></p>
       <p>{{i.description}}</p>
       <p><a class="small" data-ng-href="{{i.link}}">{{i.link}}</a></p>        
    </li>
    <li ng-if="!items.length">No Records Found</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: Just check your items.length when searching done, you can do it with the same.

Comment: Glad to see that, Good luck :)